# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp( \frac{a \ln n + b}{c \ln n + d})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp( \frac{a \ln n + b}{c \ln n + d})$$ for what values of $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb R$ the series converges?

How to solve this type of questions  i. e. series with exponent power...?
please explain...

Comment: Have you heard of ratio or root tests?

Comment: @ Arjang I know ratio and root test... is it applicable here...

Comment: Apply the tests and find the vlues that would make the test pass. Those are the values that will make the series converge.

Comment: @ Arjang..please provide more hint...

Answer (score 1):

To get some experience, first simplify the question and see what insight you glimpse, for example values for b and d does not effect the convergence.So you can look at the simpler function not including b,d. The new simplified function will only have $\frac {a}{c}$. which mean each term will be a constant. A series with infinite positive constant terms diverges. Alternatively look at the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a \ln n + b}{c \ln n + d}=\frac{a}{c}$, what does that tell about the value of infinitely many terms of the series?

Applying either the root test or ratio test will also include a reasoning similar to above.